setup function in class doesn't work as expected while passing parameterized values
I have no idea why modifying the code mentioned here to the following doesn't work? The variables are not accessible inside the tests and setup is being invoked before every test despite the scope being set to class. Any pointers would be very helpful. Thanks
#conftest.py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--data", action="store", default="1,2 3,4 5,6", help="Data for parametrization")

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    data_str = metafunc.config.getoption("data")
    # data_list = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
    data_list = [tuple(map(int, item.split(','))) for item in data_str.split()]
    # metafunc.parametrize("data", data_list, indirect=True)
    metafunc.parametrize("data", data_list, scope="class")

# @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
# def data(request):
#     return request.param

#test_code.py
import pytest
class Test1():
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
    def setup(self, data, request):
        print(data)
        [self.a, self.b] = list(data)
        self.c = self.a + self.b
        print('Test1.setup')

    def test_a(self):
        print("Test1.test_a")
        print(f'Test1.test_a - {self.a}, {self.b}, {self.c}')
        self.d = self.c * 2

    def test_b(self):
        print("Test1.test_b")
        print(f'Test1.test_b - {self.d}')

The problem should be with pytest_generate_tests because i think it is being called for every test?!

The problem with your code is the use of class scope within the setup() function. The setup function is not a class method: it is an instance method. Furthermore, I think using a class is too complicated. I prefer using test functions instead. For that, I redesign and reorganize the tests as follow:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# conftest.py

import json

import pytest


def pytest_addoption(parser: pytest.Parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--data",
        action="store",
        default="[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]",
        help="Data for parametrization",
    )


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc: pytest.Metafunc):
    # Only parametrize for the 'data' fixture
    if "data" not in metafunc.fixturenames:
        return

    # Using pytest.param() gives us the option
    # to assign an ID to the test data
    data_list = [
        pytest.param(data, id=f"a={data[0]}, b={data[1]}")
        for data in json.loads(metafunc.config.getoption("data"))
    ]
    metafunc.parametrize("data", data_list, scope="session")


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def c_value(data):
    return sum(data)


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def d_value(c_value):
    return c_value * 2


# test_code.py
import logging


def test_a(data, c_value):
    logging.debug("data=%r", data)
    logging.debug("c_value=%r", c_value)


def test_b(data, c_value, d_value):
    logging.debug("data=%r", data)
    logging.debug("c_value=%r", c_value)
    logging.debug("d_value=%r", d_value)


# pyproject.toml
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
log_cli = "true"
log_level = "DEBUG"
log_format = "%(levelname)s | %(filename)s(%(lineno)d) | %(funcName)s | %(message)s"
markers = ["slow"]


Output:
$ pytest -s -v
========================================== test session starts ===========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.12.4, pytest-8.3.1, pluggy-1.5.0 -- /var/tmp/venv/sandbox/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/haiv/temp/so/pytest-parametrize-cmdline
configfile: pyproject.toml
plugins: check-2.3.1, pythonpath-0.7.3, assume-2.4.3, anyio-4.4.0
collected 6 items                                                                                        

test_code.py::test_a[a=1, b=2] 
--------------------------------------------- live log call ----------------------------------------------
DEBUG | test_code.py(6) | test_a | data=[1, 2]
DEBUG | test_code.py(7) | test_a | c_value=3
PASSED
test_code.py::test_b[a=1, b=2] 
--------------------------------------------- live log call ----------------------------------------------
DEBUG | test_code.py(11) | test_b | data=[1, 2]
DEBUG | test_code.py(12) | test_b | c_value=3
DEBUG | test_code.py(13) | test_b | d_value=6
PASSED
test_code.py::test_a[a=3, b=4] 
--------------------------------------------- live log call ----------------------------------------------
DEBUG | test_code.py(6) | test_a | data=[3, 4]
DEBUG | test_code.py(7) | test_a | c_value=7
PASSED
test_code.py::test_b[a=3, b=4] 
--------------------------------------------- live log call ----------------------------------------------
DEBUG | test_code.py(11) | test_b | data=[3, 4]
DEBUG | test_code.py(12) | test_b | c_value=7
DEBUG | test_code.py(13) | test_b | d_value=14
PASSED
test_code.py::test_a[a=5, b=6] 
--------------------------------------------- live log call ----------------------------------------------
DEBUG | test_code.py(6) | test_a | data=[5, 6]
DEBUG | test_code.py(7) | test_a | c_value=11
PASSED
test_code.py::test_b[a=5, b=6] 
--------------------------------------------- live log call ----------------------------------------------
DEBUG | test_code.py(11) | test_b | data=[5, 6]
DEBUG | test_code.py(12) | test_b | c_value=11
DEBUG | test_code.py(13) | test_b | d_value=22
PASSED

=========================================== 6 passed in 0.02s ============================================


Discussion

Instead of parsing the data myself, I adopt the JSON format, so parsing is a matter of calling json.loads()
For data_list, I use pytest.param(), which I can name the data, resulting in a more detailed test name.
The fixtures has "session" scope because the data will not change
I put all the fixtures in conftest.py so test_code.py is clean
I use logging instead of print because logging provides more functionalities, more details than print. Furthermore, I can control the logging output by editing pyproject.toml

